# Can't turn on bluetooth on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth

Bluetooth was working fine, but stopped working after the last restart.
Using a Asus Vivobook pro 14X

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
Host: Vivobook_ASUSLaptop M7400QC_M7
Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic
```

Here is the output of

```
sudo systemctl status bluetenter code hereooth.service
```

:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-12-08 23:03:57 IST; 1min 27s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 848 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18394)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 68ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─848 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

[image: Bluetooth screenshot]

Comment: Issue fixed itself